# When combining Conda environment files and Pip, is Conda evironment active when Pip install is run?

Tags: python, pip, anaconda, conda

I am using both `pip` and `conda` to install dependencies for my project.  I keep dependencies that I wish to install via `conda` in an `environment.yml` file and dependencies which I install via `pip` inside a `requirements.txt` file (which I reference from inside the `environment.yml` file). Here is the [repo](https://github.com/kaust-vislab/tensorflow-gpu-data-science-project/tree/build-horovod-with-nccl) with the actual config files for reference.

From the install logs it appears that `conda` first runs the command

```
$ conda env create --prefix ./env --file environment.yml
```

and the runs the `pip install` command as a sub-process. However I don't understand from the logs whether or not the environment has been temporarily activated before the `pip` command is run.

I can explicitly force the desired behavior by running the following commands (after removing the reference to the `requirements.txt` file inside the `environment.yml` file)

```
$ conda env create --prefix ./env --file environment.yml
$ conda activate ./env
$ pip install -r requirements.txt
```

But I would like to know if this is what already happens "under the hood".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the environment.yml file itself you can menton the pip packages as well.You don't need to create a seperate requirements.txt file for pip packages.

Usually an environment.yml file contains the following fields:

**name** : the conda environment name

**channels**: the channels from which the dependencies needs to be installed

**dependencie:**: list of package. In that you can mention the pip dependencies as well

For more details, you can refer the following urls:

https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#create-env-file-manually

https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#create-env-from-file

The pip dependencies will be installed in the conda environment and you don't need to activate the environment and install pip dependencies manually.
Command to create conda environment:

```
conda env create -f environment.yml
```

Once the above command completes successfully, you can activate the environment and check the installed packages as below:

```
conda activate <env_name>
conda list
```

Comment: I understand how to combine `conda` and `pip` dependencies in the same environment.  I want to know if the `conda` environment is activated (or not) prior to `pip` dependencies being installed.

Comment: yes.It will be activated and installs pip packages along with other dependencies